# Copy apidoc files from dokku container to host apache folder

Tags: bash, docker, containers, dokku

I have a dokku REST app running, and I am using http://apidocjs.com/ to generate my api documentation.

The thing is i have it hosted in a digitalocean droplet. And i would like to have a bash script or something that:

1.- Executes the apidoc command
2.- Copies all of the generated files from the container to the /var/www folder in the host

What i pretend is to automatize the process, so everytime I deploy the app, the documentation is updated.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you have dokku running in a container, and you want the files that are generated there to be available to the Apache server running on your DigitalOcean droplet, not in a container.

To execute a command in a container from outside the container, you use [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)
So for instance you could run

`docker exec mycontainer /path/to/command`

To give the Apache instance access to the files, when you start the dokku container simply specify a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) where it can write the files.

Comment: Yes, that's correct: that's exactly what i want to do, but I need it to be done automatically. Nowadays I am manually entering the host and copying the files from the docker container to the www folder in the host.

What i am looking for is a way to automate the process once the deploy is finished. Something like a Nant task or similar. I looked at Wercker, but i am afraid it only performs actions inside the container, not outside, in the host.

Comment: You can use the [persistent storage](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/advanced-usage/persistent-storage/) plugin to mount a host directory into the container. You could create a post-release  plugin to build your docs and copy them out automatically.